# I want to show document from windows folder but hide the folder location?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2013, xslt-2.0, dataviewwebpart

Below is my sample code in SharePoint Data view where `@Documentlocation` is my `//server/folder/document.pdf` location. When I display this via webpart, it shows the link also. Is there way I can hide server and folder location details?

```
href=File:@Documentlocation><xsl:value-of select=@documentName
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this the whole code or it got cut off because of some reason?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is using the .htaccess file on the server to create a "fake" file path to an actual subdirectory.

Take a look at this page here: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/htaccess-fake-directory-to-actual-subdirectory/